# WinAPI - CreateFile returning FILE_TYPE_PIPE for a serial port

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

I have an RS232 adapter with four DB9M (16C950) UART serial channels (Oxford chipset).
The problem I'm encountering is that after getting the COM9's file handle (using CreateFile) its file type is FILE_TYPE_PIPE whereas all the other ports are of type FILE_TYPE_CHAR. COM9 is the only problematic one, why would that be?
It looks like it is the same problem like the one posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f655f206-527a-486a-8d29-a47e6e11ede7/getfiletype-returns-filetypepipe-for-a-serial-port-xp-net-20-platform-api?forum=vssmartdevicesnative) over a decade ago (no answers).

EDIT:
Perhaps the intent of this question was left somewhat unclear.
The reason FILE_TYPE_PIPE is problematic is due to the GetCommState call failing with such a file handle which in turn means that the DCB structure cannot be initialized and/or modified in any way.
As a consequence, port COM9 (in this case at least) as such is rendered basically unusable.

Device manager:

[image: Device manager]

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *ports[] = { "COM1", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        char *port = ports[i];
        char path[8 + 1] = "\\\\.\\";

        strcat(path, port);

        HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile
            (
                path,
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM, /* same with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL */
                NULL
            );

        DWORD fileType = GetFileType(fileHandle);

        printf("COM port: %s, file type: %d\n", port, fileType);

        CloseHandle(fileHandle);
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

[image: Code output]

Comment: what is different ? what sense at all in call `GetFileType` here ? you use hard-coded `COM_X` names. if use correct way to detect com ports by interface - you got at all `FILE_DEVICE_ACPI` device type. however if you want more exactly query type of device - direct call yourself `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with `FileFsDeviceInformation`

Comment: may be this is virtual com port which set in self device object `FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE` device type

Comment: 6, 7, 8 and 9 are all virtual ports, yes. Where can I see if FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE was set anywhere?

Comment: Check if the driver is different between COM9 and the others.

Comment: pragmatically you can instead call  `GetFileType` - direct call `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` with `FileFsDeviceInformation` and got `FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION` i guess that `DeviceType` will be `FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE`. but question - for what you need this information ?

Comment: @BenVoigt - driver can be and the same. driver can create multiple devices and different devices can have different device type.

Comment: The handle is used to retrieve the DCB structure by calling GetCommState. Maybe there is another way of getting that information? More info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363260(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so why you not direct call `GetCommState` ? for what call `GetFileType` before ?

Comment: GetFileType is called only for demonstration purposes, so as to prove the difference between COM9 and all the other ports. The code that I've posted isn't real production code at all.

Comment: Hmm, these are not virtual COM ports.  Looking at the data-sheet for OX16C950, I see it has support for IrDA (infrared transmission).  If configured that way, it would logically be a socket and that is reported as a FILE_TYPE_PIPE.  A bug in the device driver is the most likely explanation.  You don't need GetFileType(), move on with your life.

Comment: @RbMm: Sure, it's possible for a single driver to have multiple behaviors.  But different drivers is a sufficiently likely cause of different behavior to be worth checking for.

Comment: @BenVoigt - possible and different drivers, but based on the common friendly name - i assume that this is on the same driver. need look in device tree for example.